# To find out if array contains unique elements

Tags: java, arrays, unique, hashset

I'm trying to find out whether all elements in an array are unique. 
PS : I'm still a novice. So, ignore the wrong approach if there.

```
public static boolean isUnique(int[] arr)
{
    Integer[] integ = new Integer[arr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        integ[i] = arr[i];
    }
    Set<Integer> temp = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(integ));

    for (int j = 0; j < integ.length; j++)
    {
      temp.add(integ[j]);
    }
    if(temp.size()==arr.length)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: forgot to add that lol
the code fails for unique array

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the Stack Overflow [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How does it fail? Does it throw an exception or does it just give an output you don't expect? It would be much easier to help if you included your input, output and expected output in the question.

Comment: I've tried to add the full code and explanation. thanks in advance!

Comment: You still haven't asked any question. Please read all the links that Abdullah Wasi provided again. Right now, your question is no question. All one can say about it is "Okay, good luck with that.". That said, assuming that your code simply does not work (which you haven't stated), have you isolated the problem by using a debugger?

Comment: My bad, I'm new to this page. Will try following the guidelines. I got my solution though. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Aalind, you shouldn't dramatically change your question, and include in it code from the answers. This is blatantly breaking idea of QA system. Your question was essentially, how to find if array contains unique elements, so you should keep this version, and do not expand it with some other related questions. If you have other problems - create new question and discuss them there.

Comment: @Andremoniy, This is my first question tbh, and I did not read any guidelines before posting it. Also, the question before the edit was nor asked in a correct manner, hence I felt the need to change it. I'm certain of not repeating these mistakes again, but since this is my first time and I'm new to this whole coding thing, i guess I deserve some slack. :)
Regarding including the solution from the answers, it did not solve anything, just decreased the code line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with your original `isUnique()` except of some redundant code.

Your problem is that the inner loop of `SolveMagicSquare` assigns only to a single index of the `currentRow` array. Based on your question, you are using a 4x4 array. The first two times you call `isUnique(currentRow)`, `currentRow` still contains 2 or more 0s, since the last two indices of `currentRow` are not initialized yet. That's why `isUnique()` returns false.

You might want to change

```
currentRow[i] = input1[i][j];
```

to

```
currentRow[j] = input1[i][j];
```

or just past `input[i]` to `isUnique()` and eliminate both `currentRow` and the inner loop.

Answer (score 4):

Much easier would be use Java-8 approach:

```
public static boolean isUnique(int[] arr) {
    return IntStream.of(arr).distinct().toArray().length == arr.length;
}
```